# Get list of field names from a ModelSerializer class

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework

If I have a serializer such as:

```
class RandomSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = Random
        fields = ["id", "field_a", "field_b"]
```

Is there a way to access `Meta.fields` without creating an instance of the serializer?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
SimpleCompanySerializer.Meta.fields
```

does not create a new instance

```
SimpleCompanySerializer() or SimpleCompanySerializer.Meta()
```

does